# How can I sort 3 columns and assign it to one python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = {A:[1,1,1], B:[2012,3014,3343], C:[12,13,45], D:[111,222,444]}
```

but I need to join the last 3 columns in consecutive order horizontally and thus assign it to the first column, some like this:

```
df2 = {A:[1,1,1,2,2,2], Fusion3:[2012,12,111,3014,13,222]}
```

I have tried with .melt, but you are struggling with some ideas and grateful for your comments

Comment: `0012` is not valid python unless it's a string because it will raise `SyntaxError` saying `leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted;`

Comment: `df.stack().droplevel(1)` should do it.

Comment: Well, u right edited!

Answer (score 1):

From the desired output I'm making the assumption that the initial dataframe should have 1,2,3 in the A column rather 1,1,1

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[2012,3014,3343], 'C':[12,13,45], 'D':[111,222,444]})

df = df.set_index('A')
df = df.stack().droplevel(1)
```

will give you this series:

```
A
1    2012
1      12
1     111
2    3014
2      13
2     222
3    3343
3      45
3     444
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `melt`

```
out = df.melt('A').drop('variable',1)
Out[15]: 
   A  value
0  1   2012
1  2   3014
2  3   3343
3  1     12
4  2     13
5  3     45
6  1    111
7  2    222
8  3    444
```